# Actionscript 3: How to do multiple async webservice call requests

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, actionscript-3

I am using Flex and Actionscript 3, along with Webservices, rpc and a callResponder. I want to be able to, for example, say:

```
loadData1();  // Loads webservice data 1
loadData2();  // Loads webservice data 2
loadData3();  // Loads webservice data 3
```

However, Actionscript 3 works with async events, so for every call you need to wait for the ResultEvent to trigger when it is done. So, I might want to do the next request every time an event is done. However, I am afraid that threading issues might arise, and some events might not happen at all. I don't think I'm doing a good job of explaining, so I will try to show some code:

```
    private var service:Service1;
    var cp:CallResponder = new CallResponder();

    public function Webservice()
    {
        cp.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, webcalldone);
        service = new Service1();
    }
    public function doWebserviceCall()
    {
        // Check if already doing call, otherwise do this:
        cp.token = service.WebserviceTest_1("test");    
    }   
    protected function webcalldone(event:ResultEvent):void
    {
        // Get the result
        var result:String = cp.lastResult as String;

        // Check if other calls need to be done, do those
    }
```

Now, I could ofcourse save the actions in an arraylist, but whose to say that the addToArrayList and the check if other calls are available do not mess eachother up, or just miss each other, thereby halting execution? Is there something like a volatile Arraylist? Or is there a completely different, but better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an AsyncToken to keep track of which call the returned data was for http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/11/more-thoughts-on-remoting.html

Answer (score 0):

When I want to store data in an async manor I put it in an array and make a function that will "pop" the element as I send it off.
This function will be called on complete and on error events.
Yes I know there could be an issue with the server and data lost but oh well. That can also be handled
Events will always fire however, it may not be a complete event that gets fired but could be an error event.
Once the array is empty the function is done.